# How to correctly query lighting input field and Stop Form Submission?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html

How do I correctly query this field:

```
 <lightning-input-field field-name={reason3Field} id ="reason3Field"label="reason3Field" type="text" ></lightning-input-field>
```

So I can stop form submission via this onSubmit function?

```
   onSubmit(event) {

   var reason3Field3 = component.find("reason3Field").get("v.value");
    
  if(reason3Field3 !== null){
        
         event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using aura syntax in lwc. I'd recommend you go through the lwc documentation [Access Elements the Component Owns](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_components_dom_work)

additionally, you should not be using id's (this applies both to aura and lwc, since they are changed on runtime)

So, as per iterrupting the submit of your form, you probably want to `event.preventDefault();` first (regardless of any condition)

then, you will want to check for the submitted fields, you don't really need to use a query selector, as you can check the event.fields parameter on submit (as stated in the [record-edit-form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation) documentation, and subsequently, if the field and values meet your criteria, you can trigger a submit manually or throw a custom error.

Comment: Thank you for the documentation. It helps quite a bit, except it doesn't show how I'd query only the second <div>.

Comment: what div? aren't you inquiring about `lightning-input-field` ? I have further added details as to using a better approach in the asnwer

Comment: Thank you! I have found a way along with the documentation provided that will more than likely do what I want.
Thanks again.

Comment: good stuff, happy coding!